# How to disable vertical scrolling while swiping ion-slide

Tags: javascript, ionic-framework, ionic3, ion-slides

I'm building an app where I have images inside a `ion-slides` with indvidual `ion-slide` tags, when I'm swiping horizontally the scroll bar sometimes activates which moves the page and causes the user to have to re-adjust.

How can I lock the native scroll while the swipe is happening without it obstructing the use of the main scroll?

I realise I could probably hide the scrollbar while the event happens using something like `ionSlideDrag Emitted when a slide moves.` alongside `ionSlideNextEnd` and `ionSlidePrevEnd` But It this approach doesn't seem intuitive.

```
 <div class="image-container">
    <ion-slides>
      <ion-slide *ngFor="let slide of carDetails.imageUrls">
        <img [src]="slide">
      </ion-slide>
    </ion-slides>
  </div>
```

How can I essentially allow swiping while not allowing the scroll to occur?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something that wasn't mentioned in the Ionic v3 Documentation for slides is the directive `overflow-scroll="false"` which can be used to stop the scroll from overflowing when moving.

If you want scrolling for everything to be disabled you can alternatively use the following on `ionSlideDrag` alongside a `ionSlideNextEnd` or `ionSlidePrevEnd`.

```
.no-scroll{
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

Comment: Hey dude, would you be able to share a working example? I tried `overflow-scroll="false"` but it didn't work...

Comment: It seems like overflow-scroll has been replaced with scrollX and scrollY